# maya python print state of checkbox?

Tags: python, checkbox, maya

I'm trying to get the state of a checkbox in a maya UI using python. I was wondering if someone would help me. currently when the user hits the Distribute button, it calls a function which should print the true/false state of the 'x' checkbox.

```
import maya.cmds as cmds

class createMyLayoutCls(object):
    def __init__(self, *args):
        pass

    def show(self):
        self.createMyLayout()

    def createMyLayout(self):

        #check to see if our window exists
        if cmds.window('utility', exists = True):
            cmds.deleteUI('utility')

        # create our window
        self.window = cmds.window('utility', widthHeight = (200, 200), title = 'Distribute', resizeToFitChildren=1, sizeable = False)

        cmds.setParent(menu=True)

        # create a main layout
        mainLayout = cmds.columnLayout(w = 200, h = 200, cw = 10, rs = 8, co = ['both',2])

        # X Control
        self.xAxis = cmds.checkBox('X')

        # Distribute Button
        btnDistribute = cmds.button(label = 'Distribute', width = 200, height = 40, c = self.GetSelectedNodes)

        # show window
        cmds.showWindow(self.window)

    def GetSelectedNodes(self,*args):
        cal = cmds.checkBox(self['X'],q = True, v = True)
        print cal

b_cls = createMyLayoutCls()  
b_cls.show()
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you need to pass the checkbox's name  into the call to checkBox in GetSelectedNodes:

```
def GetSelectedNodes(self,*args):
    cal = cmds.checkBox(self.xAxis,q = True, v = True)
    print cal
```